# Date & Time Picker Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, calendar, timepicker

I am trying to set Date and Time for an event through the use of seperate date and time pickers for start and end times.

Start Date and Start Time
End Date and End time

The code I have put together updates the date but Time is not changing

Can anybody guide with respect to the issue?

thanks

Code is below:

```
private val START_CAL_ID = 456
private lateinit var endCalendar: Calendar
private val END_CAL_ID = 678
private lateinit var endTimeCalendar: Calendar
```

private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

On Click date it shows Date picker and on click time it shows timepicker

```
private fun showCalendar(calendarId: Int) {
    val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(
        this,
        R.style.DateTimePickerTheme,
        { datePicker: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int ->

            if (calendarId == START_CAL_ID) {
                startCalendar.set(year, month, day)
            } else if (calendarId == END_CAL_ID) {
                endCalendar.set(year, month, day)
            }
            updateDateFields()
        },
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    )
    datePicker.show()
}

private fun showTime(calendarId: Int) {
    val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
        this, R.style.DateTimePickerTheme,
        { view: TimePicker?, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int ->
            if (calendarId == START_CAL_ID) {
                startCalendar.set(hourOfDay, minute)
            } else if (calendarId == END_CAL_ID) {
                endCalendar.set(hourOfDay, minute)
            }
            updateTimeFields()
        },
        calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        false
    )
    timePickerDialog.show()
}
```

Updating the fields in the app to show the selected data in the right format

```
    private fun updateDateFields() {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editEventStartDate).text = formatter.format(startCalendar.time)
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editEventEndDate).text = formatter.format(endCalendar.time)

}

private fun updateTimeFields() {
    val timeFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm a", Locale.getDefault())
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editEventStartTime).text =
        timeFormatter.format(startCalendar.time)
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editEventEndTime).text = timeFormatter.format(endCalendar.time)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`set(int,int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#set(int,%20int)) in `Calendar` takes in the field id in its first argument and value in second. To set hour and minute, split it to two calls, e.g.

```
startCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
startCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
```

(Also, consider using java.time APIs instead. They are much nicer to work with.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate helper classes of getting time and date for nicer and clean code.

Date Picker Helper:

```
class DatePicker(var context: Context, var iface : DateTimePickerInterface?) : 

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance()
    fun showDatePicker(){
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            context,
            R.style.DateTimePickerTheme,
            this,
            selectedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            selectedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            selectedDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }
    override fun onDateSet(p0: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR,year)
        selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,month)
        selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day)
        iface?.onDateTimeSelected(selectedDate)
    }


    interface DateTimePickerInterface {
        fun onDateTimeSelected(calendar: Calendar)
    }

}
```

You can use it in Activity or Fragment like this:

```
    JustDatePicker(this@Activity,lang.toString(),object : JustDatePicker.DateTimePickerInterface {
                    override fun onDateTimeSelected(calendar: Calendar) {
                        val date : Date = calendar.time
                        //todo
                    }
    
                }).showDatePicker()
```

Similarly the TimePicker class.

```
   class JustTimePicker(var context: Context, var iface : TimePickerInterface?,var  selectedTime: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()) : TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    fun showPicker(){

        val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
            context,
            this,
            selectedTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            selectedTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            true
        )
        timePickerDialog.show()

    }


    override fun onTimeSet(p0: TimePicker?, hour: Int, min: Int) {
        selectedTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour)
        selectedTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,min)
        iface?.onTimeSelected(selectedTime)
    }

    interface TimePickerInterface {
        fun onTimeSelected(calendar: Calendar)
    }
}
```

and finally time picker used in fragment or activity like this:

```
 JustTimePicker(context!!,object : JustTimePicker.TimePickerInterface{
                    override fun onTimeSelected(calendar: Calendar) {
                     val time =       calendar.time
                        //todo
                    }
                }).showPicker()
```